# How to make an android OS skin?

Tags: android, operating-system

So there is stock Android and then other skins, like samsung's skin.
I would like to know if anyone could tell me how do i go about making an android OS skin:

What programs to use.
Any tutorials you know.

Comment: Make the question like "How to make an android OS skin?"